# Can I purchase less than 100 shares with options trading is it only 100 per call/put?

Tags: options

I want to trade options but with less than 100 shares with options is this possible or not? Is there any resources to get me answers instead of having to watch endless hours and/or articles that go around my questions. thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if you can sell a covered call option where you don't have 100 shares to cover the contract should you get assigned?

Comment: No. I was asking if I can buy options for an equity less than a 100 shares like the traditional option

Comment: 100 shares is the standard for convenience. In my lifetime, I have seen contracts for 105 or 102, but those extra shares are due to stock splits that occur during lifetime of the contract. These are very rare and are mathematically the same as 100 shares.

Comment: The worst of the bunch are complex mergers (uneven number of shares, PIL and even rights) can make adjusted option contracts very tricky to grasp the numbers. Yes, the math works out but it's easy to make an evaluation mistake. Stay away from adjusted options unless you own the precursor.

Comment: You don't ever need to own shares to trade options. Common misconception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear.  Are you referring to option contracts that are for less than 100 shares?

Traditional options are for 100 shares.  A number of years ago the CBOE tried a pilot program with option contracts on 10 shares for about a dozen or so high priced stocks and indices (Mini Contracts).  It didn't catch on.  I don't know if there are any remaining vestiges of that program.  Google for up to date info.

Comment: I meant traditional options. Is there any alternatives? There is an etf like UPRO and GUSH. Is there an other etfs that could be shorted that are similar?